# Is there a faster way than looping through document paragraphs?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Complete novice. I created a Word document using Pandoc but the Arabic output required some modification. Scraping through online documentation and posts, I have got the following code:

```
Sub pandoc_RTL()
'
' pandoc_RTL Macro
'
'

Dim objPara As Paragraph

    For Each objPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        If objPara.Style = "body AR" Then
            objPara.Range.Select            
            Selection.RtlRun
            Selection.RtlPara
        End If

        If objPara.Style = "hadith AR" Then
            objPara.Range.Select
            Selection.RtlRun
            Selection.RtlPara
        End If

        If objPara.Style = "hadith in-list AR" Then
            objPara.Range.Select
            Selection.RtlRun
            Selection.RtlPara
        End If

        If objPara.Style = "athar AR" Then
            objPara.Range.Select
            Selection.RtlRun
            Selection.RtlPara
        End If

        If objPara.Style = "body AR" Then
            objPara.Range.Select
            Selection.RtlRun
            Selection.RtlPara
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

My questions:

1. Is Regex the only way to avoid repetition since all the required styles end with “AR”?
2. Is there a faster way to do this besides looping through all the paragraphs?

Comment: You could, of course, simply modify the Style attributes...

Comment: @macropod, do you mean Microsoft Word?

Comment: Where else would you expect Style attributes in a Word document to be found?

Comment: I thought it was something in VBA as well. The direction radio buttons are disabled when modifying the styles, am I missing something? I've changed the paragraph style language to Arabic already.

Answer (score 1):

You need only modify the Styles. The radio buttons for this are accessible via Manage Styles>Modify>Format>Paragraph>Indents and Spacing in any document for which an RTL language has been enabled. In any event, using VBA:

```
Dim i As Long, ArrStl
ArrStl = Array("body AR", "hadith AR", "hadith in-list AR", "athar AR")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStl)
  ActiveDocument.Styles(ArrStl(i)).ParagraphFormat.ReadingOrder = wdReadingOrderRtl
Next
```

Done.

Comment: That's exactly where I checked:https://imgur.com/a/iIes2UV How to check if RTL language has been enabled for the current document?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to do anything with the document.

Comment: It does when I run it (using Styles I have, such as 'Normal').

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. I had missed a style and was checking those paragraphs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's messing up the punctuation.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with punctuation. If your punctuation ends up messed up, that can only be because it was wrong in the first place. Your own code would likely do the same.

Comment: Here is a comparison: https://imgur.com/a/1EMchjU Please download the image to see the difference clearly. You can download the plain text of the Arabic here: https://pastebin.com/sW2FiL5k

Comment: See my previous comment. Trying to progressively select the content at pastebin from right to left clearly shows it is not correctly formatted there.

Comment: That's because it doesn't support flowing from RTL. If you open the text in Notepad++ and enable RTL flow, everything is fine. I've used the same method with InDesign as well, it showed up fine.

Comment: Regardless, changing the text direction cannot of itself correct such flaws in the content. Such flaws can only be corrected on a paragraph-by-paragraph basis and, to do so with a macro would require both a method of identifying such errors and correcting them.